# MYSQL: Grouping by week intervals, where greater then Monday

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, group-by

Say we have a `posts` table that has the columns: `id, title, expires_at`. We want to show how many posts where not "expired" in each week of every year.

Maybe a simpler way of putting it would be: "a count of posts grouped by weeks of the year where the `expires_at` date is great then the start of each week"

For example:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|   Year    |   Week    |   posts_not_expired   |
------------|-----------|-----------------------|
|   2017    |   01      |   22                  |
|   2017    |   02      |   103                 |
|   2017    |   03      |   7                   |
|   ...     |   ...     |   ...                 |
|   2009    |   52      |   63                  |
|-----------|-----------|-----------------------|
```

What we have so far:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as posts_not_expired,
    YEAR(expires_at) * 100 as Year,
    YEARWEEK(expires_at) as Week,
FROM posts
GROUP BY Year, Week
```

Comment: have you attempted a SQL query?

Comment: Yes an its failing, i don't want to clutter the answer here with bad SQL.

Comment: can you provide a small sample set, that would create this result? Putting it in a http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be even better.

Comment: @Sean example above will also provide sqlfiddle :-)

Comment: change ORDER BY to GROUP BY

Comment: should the start of week be Sunday or Monday?

Comment: oops :-) monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DAYOFWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) to count non-expired posts for a given week. (where 1 = Sunday,2=Monday,..7=Saturday)

```
SELECT
    YEAR(expires_at) as `Year`,
    WEEKOFYEAR(expires_at) as `Week`,
    SUM(DAYOFWEEK(expires_at) > 2) as `posts_not_expired`
FROM posts
GROUP BY YEAR(expires_at), WEEKOFYEAR(expires_at)
```

Comment: Wow... So simple!  Thank you.

Comment: One last thing, how can i format "Week" to be just he number of the week rather then 200917?

Comment: use `weekofyear`.